# WPF TreeView Add / Delete Item

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I am new to WPF and I am learning about TreeView.  I would like add a hardcoded item (string) to a TreeView and remove it on expand event.

How do I do that?

Much appreciated

Comment: seems like you started another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35517629/wpf-treeview-not-redrawing